# Guava 15 lib in jboss as 7.2

Tags: java, jboss, guava

My webapp using guava-15.jar lib, but in start jboss as 7.2 results exception:

```
17:26:57,330 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set)]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    ... 3 more
```

But if remove library my application works.

Comment: `ServiceManager` is `@Beta` even as of 16.0.1. Does Spring actually use it? Maybe it has a dependency on a guava version 14.something?

Comment: The webapp using selenium and selenium library has dependency with guava-15 lib.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this post, but in case anyone else comes across this...

This appears to be due to Guava 15.0 being deployed into a CDI 1.0 container.

See this post/fix, especially comment #16 (if using maven). I can't speak to whether they've created this cdi1.0 jar for versions 16 or 17.

[Guava 15 cannot be deployed in an environment using CDI 1.0 such as JEE6](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1527)

For convenience, the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>15.0</version>
  <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
</dependency>
```